# Importing Chai in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, chai

I'm trying to use chai in typescript.

Chai's javascript example shows this as:

```
var should = require('chai').should();
```

I downloaded the type definition:

```
tsd install chai
```

...referenced the file, tried to import

```
/// <reference path='../typings/chai/chai.d.ts' />
import should = require('chai').should();
```

I get:

```
error TS1005: ';' expected
```

...any idea how to do this?

Comment: I'm using Version 1.5.0-beta

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [tests](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/chai/chai-tests.ts) for the chai typings do the following:

```
import chai = require('chai');
var should = chai.should();
```

Does that work for you?

Comment: Thanks Vadim.  Both this method, and a previous answer (since deleted) which mentioned ES6 syntax (import * as chai from 'chai') lead to "Mocha exploded! Error: Cannot find module 'chai'"

Comment: Apparently I wasn't satisfying devDependencies per "Mocha and Chai are devDependencies so that means when you use them in your project as a module, i.e. it appears under the node_modules directory of your project, then these will not be fetched and installed."  https://github.com/peter-murray/node-hue-api/issues/8

Comment: check `import { .should } from 'chai'` answer for es6 syntax

Answer (score 23):

```
import { should } from 'chai';
should();
```

Comment: it annoys me that this is the correct answer.  it feels bad.  another trap is that if you run your whole suite, you can get away with this only running in the first file, meaning it's easy to forget to add it.

Answer (score 4):

```js
import { expect } from 'chai';
import 'chai/register-should';
```

to use both `expect` and `should`

Comment: this should work according to the docs, but (for me at least) just moans about no such module or whatever.

Comment: indeed, the last version of chai (4.3.6) is buggy. Install 4.3.3 instead
npm i chai@4.3.3 --save-dev