# Typescript @types/chai - how do you use Chai.Assertion?

Tags: typescript, chai

I'm trying to use chai in typescript and I can't get any of the assertions to work as I would expect.

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
  "@types/chai": "^4.0.1",
  "@types/mocha": "^2.2.41",
  "chai": "^4.1.0",
  "mocha": "^3.4.2",
  "typescript": "2.4.2"
}
```

All of these emit compiler errors:

```
import * as chai from 'chai';
const expect = chai.expect;
const assert = chai.assert;

const expect = chai.expect;
expect(myVar).to.be.empty();
expect(myVar).to.be.empty;
expect(myVar).to.be.undefined();
expect(myVar).to.be.undefined;
```

If I try to import assertions directly - I don't see empty() as a valid assertion:

```
const assert = chai.assert;
assert.empty??? not there?
```

Any ideas are welcome.

Thanks - Chad

---

**Quick answer**

Shaun points out below - change the import to:

```
import { assert, expect } from 'chai';
```

Thanks Shaun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the types do not include `isEmpty(...)` for the `assert`; that [will probably change for `4.0.3`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/18835/files). In the meantime, we can cast `assert as any` and call `isEmpty(...)` on that.

Once you have the types installed, this might work for you:

```
import chai = require("chai");
const assert = chai.assert;
const expect = chai.expect;

expect("").to.be.empty;
expect(undefined).to.be.undefined;
(assert as any).isEmpty("");
```

Another alternative is destructuring on import:

```
import { assert, expect } from "chai";

expect("").to.be.empty;
expect(undefined).to.be.undefined;
(assert as any).isEmpty("");
```

Here is how those look in VSCode.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Shawn - I was explicitly talking about the ones that are typed as :Assertion's -- like   true: Assertion;
        false: Assertion;
        null: Assertion;
        undefined: Assertion;
        NaN: Assertion;
        exist: Assertion;
        empty: Assertion;            ;;;;    I have equals and other working fine

Comment: @chadbr Thank you for letting me know. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: destructuring on import did the trick! it breaks tslint -- but I can add an ignore for that. Interesting side is I tried that a few months back and it did not work -- so I didn't even try again. thanks much Shaun.

Answer (score 0):

Additional to Shaun's Answer: If you need to import *Should* Chai Interface...

```
import { assert, expect } from "chai"; //Import the Expect & Assert Interfaces
import 'chai/register-should'; // Import the Should Interface
```

Reference;
[Importing Chai in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31531256/importing-chai-in-typescript/40405072)

https://www.chaijs.com/guide/styles/#should